# AWS Lambda error on build Node with Sharp Library

Tags: amazon-web-services, javascript

I have a problem to build my lambda handler. I'm trying to use sharp library to do an image resize on S3.

My code:

```js
S3.getObject({
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: objectKey
}, (err, data) => {
    SHARP(data.Body).resize(250, 250).toFormat("jpg").toBuffer().then((buffer) => {
        S3.putObject({
            Body: buffer,
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: objectKey,
            ContentType: "image/jpeg",
            ContentDisposition: "inline",
        })
    })
});
```

My node dependencies:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.637.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "sharp": "^0.29.1",
    "util": "^0.12.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "esbuild": "^0.12.27",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
```

My code to build:

```json
esbuild --bundle --minify --platform=node --target=node12 --outdir=build index.js && cd build && zip index.js.zip index.js
```

AWS Lambda error:

```json
Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp-linux-x64.node'
Require stack:
- /var/task/index.js
- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js
- /var/runtime/index.js

Possible solutions:
- Install with the --verbose flag and look for errors: "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp"
- Install for the current runtime: "npm install --platform=linux --arch=x64 sharp"
- Consult the installation documentation: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install
```

Comment: This question might be better on server fault. The message says it can't find sharp, but exactly why is  more a question for developers than infrastructure people I think. I use AWS SAM to do deployments of the odd bit of software I need to deploy

Comment: I thought about AWS SAM, but how I'm new on this world, I have fear to configure that in a development machine, but is a good way, I can try this. Thanks for the tips, @Tim!

Comment: AWS SAM may help with dependencies and deployment. I found it easier than trying to do packaging and such myself. It's not super complex but it does take a little bit of time to learn and get working, but should hopefully save time overall.